# What is the exact behaviour of an INSERT IGNORE.... SELECT.... ORDER BY... LIMIT... in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, insert-select, sql-limit

In MySql 5.6 I have a query similar to the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE_1 (field_a,field_b)
SELECT field_a,field_b
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE
...
ORDER BY field_a
LIMIT 0,10
```

`TABLE_1` is a temporary table that is used to store some tuples and then emptied. It doesn't have a PRIMARY KEY.

Since the process fills the table in multiple times, it may happen that it may contain tuples found throught the `SELECT`. Considering this, I thought about increasing the limit, so that I would be able to insert all the needed data.

Here is an example of the content of `TABLE_1` and of the result of the `SELECT` query.

`TABLE_1`:

```
+---------+---------+
| field_a | field_b |
+---------+---------+
| foo     | 1       |
| foo     | 2       |
| foo     | 3       |
| foo     | 4       |
| bar     | 2       |
| bar     | 3       |
| bar     | 4       |
| bar     | 5       |
+---------+---------+
```

`SELECT` result (ignoring `LIMIT`):

```
+---------+---------+
| field_a | field_b |
+---------+---------+
| foo     | 4       |
| foo     | 5       |
| foo     | 6       |
| foo     | 7       |
| foo     | 8       |
| foo     | 9       |
| foo     | 10      |
| foo     | 11      |
| foo     | 12      |
| foo     | 13      |
| bar     | 5       |
| bar     | 6       |
| bar     | 7       |
| bar     | 8       |
+---------+---------+
```

So, considering that there are two duplicate tuples, `(foo,4)` and `(bar,5)`, I expected 8 elements to be inserted... while, I actually found that the query inserted 10 elements, ignoring the two duplicates.

The point is that I can't find the reason of this behavior in the docs. I found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-features-limit.html) that `LIMIT` works in `INSERT...SELECT` only if there is an `ORDER BY`, which I have. But I was not able to find a precise description of this behavior, having together `INSERT IGNORE`, `INSERT...SELECT`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Can somebody help me to explain this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `create table` statement.  I don't believe that (`field_a`, `field_b`) are really the primary key on the table.

Comment: TABLE_1 is just an example table, to explain my situation. But, even though I was pretty sure they are primary keys, you are right, they are not. I'm editing the question immediately!

Comment: @clami219 With your data and a combined primary key on `(field_a, field_b)` for `table_1` I get `8 row(s) affected Records: 10  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 0`

Comment: @VMai As pointed out by Gordon Linoff, I was actually wrong on the primary keys... sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

[Manual for `INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html):

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, *errors that occur* while executing the `INSERT` statement are ignored.

It is likely that there is no unique constraint on (`field_a, field_b)` on `TABLE_1`. No "duplicate" error can occur without such a constraint. `TABLE_2`'s primary key (which is a special case of unique constraint) has no effect in your query.

Also, `LIMIT n` without `ORDER BY` "works", it just returns the first `n` random rows that the query happens to generate.

Comment: So, how do you explain the 10 inserts without duplication?